# How to prove $f(x)=\cos x$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

I don't know how to prove $f(x) = \cos x$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ (continuous in every range)

Comment: The proof will depend on your definition of the cosinus.

Comment: @Marc Thank you for replying.
Would you mind telling me a little bit of a little bit of a theorem or hint?

Comment: I can't give you a hint until you tell me your definition of the cosinus function.

Comment: @Marc there's a fairly standard geometric definition of the cosine of an angle in radians

Comment: $|\cos(y)-\cos(x)|=\left|\int_x^y \sin(t) dt \right| \leq |y-x|$

Comment: Alternatively, it suffices to note that
$$
\cos(x) - \cos(y) = -2 \sin\left(\frac{x+y}{2} \right)\sin\left(\frac{x-y}{2} \right)
$$

Comment: thank you every one! Sorry, I am Korean because I am not good at English. You asked me about definition. It is a typical trigonometric function! and there is answer what i want!! one more time thank you!

Comment: @장원봉: "It is a typical trigonometric function", yes, it is. But the *definition* of this function is a highly nontrivial business: one might **define** it in terms of series. In a course of real analysis, one should not take for granted anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$ and $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$. Then we require that
$$\left|f(x)-f(y)\right|<\epsilon\implies \left|\cos x-\cos y\right|<\epsilon\implies \left|-2\sin \frac{x+y}2\sin\frac{x-y}2\right| < \epsilon$$
Since 
$$\left|-2\sin \frac{x+y}2\sin\frac{x-y}2\right|\le 2\left|\sin\frac{x-y}2\right|$$
we show that
$$2\left|\sin\frac{x-y}2\right|<\epsilon$$
and thus
$$\left|x-y\right|<\delta\implies \left|\frac{x-y}2\right|<\delta$$
As $\left|\sin x\right|\le \left|x\right|$,
$$2\left|\sin\frac{x-y}2\right|\le 2\left|\frac{x-y}2\right|<2\delta$$

Setting a $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{2}>0$ will work and since that $\delta$ does not depend on $x,y$, we have uniform continuity.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the definition of "continuous." If you are encountering this problem in a course in calculus or or real analysis, that will be the delta-epsilon definition that
"f(x) is continuous at point $x_0$ iff for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists some $\delta>0$ (whose value might depend on on $\epsilon$ and $x_0$) such that $|x_1 - x_0| < \delta$ implies $|f(x_1)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon$."

In the case of $f(x) = \cos x$, if $x_1 = x_0 + \delta$,
$$
f(x_1)-f(x_0) = \cos (x_0 + \delta) - \cos x_0 = \cos x_0 \cos \delta  - \sin x_0 \sin \delta  - \cos x_0 \\= \cos x_0 (\cos \delta-1) -\sin x_0\sin\delta 
$$
Now choose $\delta = \frac14 \epsilon$.  Then since $\delta>0$
$$
\sin x_0 \sin \delta < x_0 \delta = \frac14\epsilon \\
\cos x_0 (\cos \delta-1) < \cos x_0 \delta < \frac14\epsilon \\
$$
so $$
f(x_1)-f(x_0) < \frac \epsilon 2 < \epsilon
$$